# Can't log into roundcube webmail on my own private mailserver

Tags: email, smtp, imap, webmail

I just set up smtp and imap (so postfix and dovecot) on my debian machine and have an own domain. I tested that i can e.g. send emails and everything works. Now i installed Roundcube Webmail and wanted to log in. As far as i understand, you have to log into Roundcube as the system user (unix) unless using virtual mailboxes. So i have many users like root, "user" and some other user accounts on my machine that have other normal names. I want to log into roundcube now.

**Problem**: I try to log in as *username*@my-domain.tld and as the password i type the system user password. It says authentication failure, so password is incorrect.
If it's not the system user password, which password is it and where is the password stored?

the config in `./config/config.inc.php` file:

```
<?php

/* Local configuration for Roundcube Webmail */

// ----------------------------------
// SQL DATABASE
// ----------------------------------
// Database connection string (DSN) for read+write operations
// Format (compatible with PEAR MDB2): db_provider://user:password@host/database
// Currently supported db_providers: mysql, pgsql, sqlite, mssql, sqlsrv, oracle
// For examples see http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.mdb2.intro-dsn.php
// Note: for SQLite use absolute path (Linux): 'sqlite:////full/path/to/sqlite.db?mode=0646'
//       or (Windows): 'sqlite:///C:/full/path/to/sqlite.db'
// Note: Various drivers support various additional arguments for connection,
//       for Mysql: key, cipher, cert, capath, ca, verify_server_cert,
//       for Postgres: application_name, sslmode, sslcert, sslkey, sslrootcert, sslcrl, sslcompression, service.
//       e.g. 'mysql://roundcube:@localhost/roundcubemail?verify_server_cert=false'
$config['db_dsnw'] = 'mysql://*REDACTED_dbuser*:*REDACTED db_password*@localhost/roundcubemail';

// ----------------------------------
// IMAP
// ----------------------------------
// The IMAP host (and optionally port number) chosen to perform the log-in.
// Leave blank to show a textbox at login, give a list of hosts
// to display a pulldown menu or set one host as string.
// Enter hostname with prefix ssl:// to use Implicit TLS, or use
// prefix tls:// to use STARTTLS.
// If port number is omitted it will be set to 993 (for ssl://) or 143 otherwise.
// Supported replacement variables:
// %n - hostname ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
// %t - hostname without the first part
// %d - domain (http hostname $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] without the first part)
// %s - domain name after the '@' from e-mail address provided at login screen
// For example %n = mail.domain.tld, %t = domain.tld
// WARNING: After hostname change update of mail_host column in users table is
//          required to match old user data records with the new host.
$config['imap_host'] = 'tls://localhost';

// ----------------------------------
// SMTP
// ----------------------------------
// SMTP server host (and optional port number) for sending mails.
// Enter hostname with prefix ssl:// to use Implicit TLS, or use
// prefix tls:// to use STARTTLS.
// If port number is omitted it will be set to 465 (for ssl://) or 587 otherwise.
// Supported replacement variables:
// %h - user's IMAP hostname
// %n - hostname ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
// %t - hostname without the first part
// %d - domain (http hostname $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] without the first part)
// %z - IMAP domain (IMAP hostname without the first part)
// For example %n = mail.domain.tld, %t = domain.tld
// To specify different SMTP servers for different IMAP hosts provide an array
// of IMAP host (no prefix or port) and SMTP server e.g. ['imap.example.com' => 'smtp.example.net']
$config['smtp_host'] = 'tls://localhost';

// provide an URL where a user can get support for this Roundcube installation
// PLEASE DO NOT LINK TO THE ROUNDCUBE.NET WEBSITE HERE!
$config['support_url'] = '';

// This key is used for encrypting purposes, like storing of imap password
// in the session. For historical reasons it's called DES_key, but it's used
// with any configured cipher_method (see below).
// For the default cipher_method a required key length is 24 characters.
$config['des_key'] = '*REDACTED*';

// ----------------------------------
// PLUGINS
// ----------------------------------
// List of active plugins (in plugins/ directory)
$config['plugins'] = [];
```